# Connecting Keycloak with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to just simply connect my keycloak with postgresql.  Keycloak and postgres are running on the same machine. Here are the sections from my standalone.xml file:

### DataSources

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://10.76.106.4:5432/keycloakSQL</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>KeycloakAdmin</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                ​<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                        ​<xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    ​</driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

### Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.23.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Here is the error that I am getting when attempting to run the standalone.bat:

### Error

```
E:\keycloak\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "E:\keycloak\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "E:\keycloak"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "

===============================================================================

15:02:41,211 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
15:02:43,937 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
15:02:43,953 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
15:02:44,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 15.0.2 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) starting
15:02:45,483 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.15.3.Final
15:02:50,702 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) OPVDX002: Failed to pretty print validation error: null
15:02:50,706 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:403)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [152,14]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:651)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:205)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_16.java:673)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:243)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:140)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:144)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [152,14]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:634)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:504)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:488)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1223)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:208)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:189)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:644)
        ... 14 more

15:02:50,712 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
15:02:50,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 15.0.2 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) stopped in 7ms
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am also attaching a screenshot of my postgresql instance, in the case it maybe help.
[postgres screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlfQ4.jpg)

Comment: `Failed to parse configuration` indicates syntax error in the config file - validate XML syntax of your config files.

Comment: I agree with Jan. I'd check the XML file. Given the line number (152), I'd start with standalone.xml. See if there's some odd character, perhaps a non-printable control char?

Comment: In fact, I copied and pasted your standalone.xml into vim and got this: `<200b><driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                        <200b><xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    <200b></driver>`